# maximum number of pairwise disjoint and pairwise non adjacent paths in the hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given any (not necessarily proper) vertex two-colouring of the n-hypercube, $G_n = (V_n, E_n)$ and $V_n = \{0,1\}^n, \{v_1,v_2\} \in E_n$ iff $v_1$ and $v_2$ differ in exactly on coordinate.
I will refer to the colours as red and blue in the following.
There exists a node of WLOG blue colour that has the least number of adjacent blue coloured nodes out of all blue nodes. For this node, I am trying to find a formula that gives the maximum number of pairwise node-disjoint paths to any set of red nodes in $V_n$. Also, every path needs to be pairwise non adjacent to any other path. This is equivalent to choosing any direction, e.g. the x-,y-, or z-axis in $G_3$ at most once.

Thanks in advance for ideas!

Comment: You have the trivial lower bound 'number of adjacent red nodes' and the two upper bounds 'total  number of red nodes' and 'number of directions' which is $n$. I would guess that one can make a coloring that achieves any number that satisfies these three bounds so I don't think there is more of a formula that works in general.

Comment: As for upper and lower bounds, I also have thought about that. The question is, for any given two colouring to come up with a formula. So it is not about constructing a two colouring any chosen number. Another upper bound is (n + number of adjacent red nodes)/2